# Why is Eclipse/Maven project not picking up the values from settings.xml?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have saved the configuration at the bottom in c:\users\username\.m2\settings.xml but pom.xml created as part of Maven Project in Eclipse is not picking up the values. The effective POM still has

```xml
  <repositories>  
    <repository>  
      <snapshots>  
        <enabled>false</enabled>  
      </snapshots>  
      <id>central</id>  
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>  
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>  
    </repository>  
  </repositories>
```

And what should be the http://ebr.springsource.com/respository equivalent of

```xml
  <pluginRepositories>  
    <pluginRepository>  
      <releases>  
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>  
      </releases>  
      <snapshots>  
        <enabled>false</enabled>  
      </snapshots>  
      <id>central</id>  
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>  
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>  
    </pluginRepository>  
  </pluginRepositories>
```

### settings.xml

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"  
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0  
                              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">  
  <repositories>  
      <repository>  
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>  
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>  
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>  
      </repository>  

      <repository>  
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>  
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>  
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>  
      </repository>  
  </repositories>  
</settings>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add it to the home folder of the user who executes mvn command

By default your settings.xml is being looked up in:

- The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
- A user's install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: Eclipse->Preferences->Maven->User Settings->User Settings point to "c:\Users\<username>\.m2\settings.xml" and "Open file" option opens the correct file.  Would "$M2_Home/conf/settings.xml" override "${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml"?

Comment: If you have settings.xml in both locations, they will be merged to produce effective settings.xml

Comment: Still doesn't work for me :(. M2_HOME is correctly pointing to the parent folder of conf. Effective pom is not reading the settings.xml plug-in repositories. Any suggestions?